# Elasticsearch won't find any results for a search containing letters

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm begining with elasticsearch in java.

I can make a query that matches documents having a property containing a text. This property is a string.

The results are strange: when I'm searching for numbers in a string, I have some results but as soon as the query contains a letter no results are returned.

Here is a summary of the current behavior:

I have 2 documents :

```
{
  model:"123",
  serialNumber: "123"
}
```

and

```
{
  model:"123",
  serialNumber: "TT123"
}
```

If I'm searching for "123" I have 2 results => OK

If I'm searching for "TT", I have no results.

I'm using wildcard.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
BoolQueryBuilder bqb = new BoolQueryBuilder();
bqb.should(new WildcardQueryBuilder("serialNumber", "*TT*"));
/*or bqb.should(new WildcardQueryBuilder("serialNumber", "*123*"));*/

return QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(bqb, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "*tt*" find 2 results? Wildcard queries are not analyzed, but your analyzed index probably is so the index contains "tt123", which will not match "*TT*" but "*tt*" will.

That said, Wildcards are slow, you should should look into other analyzers, such as [ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to create your index.

Comment: Yes it does ! As I'ms really a beginer, could you please explain me how to ignore case ?

Comment: Simply call toLoweCase() to whatever string you you hold the TT in